# Puppeteer invoking onChange event handler not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, puppeteer

Banging my head against this wall for a bit, hoping someone may have some advice.

I am trying to invoke the onChange handler in a page loaded into Puppeteer.  While I am able to select the appropriate option within the select (verified by turning off headless) I am unable to get the event handler to run.

1) Puppeteer provides the [page.select()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselectselector-values) method, which explicitly states

> "Triggers a change and input event once all the provided options have
>   been selected"

I am able to select the expected option, but the event handler does not fire

```
await page.select('select#venue', '40');
```

2) Using native javascript inside a page.evaluate() call to manually select the required option, then generate a new Event and manually using element.dispatchEvent(event) e.g.

```
document.querySelector('select#venue > option:nth-child(4)').selected = "selected";

const event = new Event('change', {bubbles: true});
event.simulated = true;

document.querySelector('select#venue').dispatchEvent(event));
```

3) Using jQuery inside a page.evaluate() call to manually select the required otpion, then trigger the event e.g.

```
$("select#venue").val(17).change();
```

Completely out of ideas folks, and thoughts appreciated!

Comment: have you solved this? Am facing a similar issue..

Comment: How is this `select` generated? I mean, is it a native HTML element or is manipulated by a jQuery plugin or something like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was searching for same thing, to trigger an "onchange" event on a text field. I modified your code a little and it worked:

```
const myValue = 17;
await page.$eval('#selector', (element, myValue) => {
    element.value = myValue;
    const event = new Event('change');
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}, myValue);
```

Comment: Triggering events is a good alternative if HTMLElement.click() does not work. This method worked for me.